# react I want to change the order

Tags: reactjs

When the button is pressed, I want it to swipe in the following order: yellow, red, blue, green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. Now, it is working fine, I guess.

**You were subtracting `back.length` (not valid) whereas you hav to do `background.length` for `z-index`**

I have added `position: relative` and `z-index` to the other `Box` in `else` as well. Earlier, the card at the last was having highest preference die to no `z-index` but now it is fine.

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-swartz-1u70q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I went to the url, but it won't open.

Comment: The message "sandbox not found" is displayed.

Comment: I thought you have gone through it deleted it. check in 5mins

Comment: Check the link now.